# Do CSS background animation on big elements without overflow hidden on body and keeping the scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I was wondering if there was a method on how to animate big objects on the background without affecting the scrolling on the page, because the current situation I am in, overflows the objects when using position: absolute; on the background items, and if I want to remove the scrolling of the objects with overflow: hidden; then the whole page looses it's scroll with is also another thing I don't want.

Any ideas?

Working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mx0zns4o/

SCSS:

```
body{
  background: grey;
}

.circles {
        &.closing {
            .bigCircle {
                animation: bigCircleIn 1s 0s;
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.86, 0, .07, 1);
            }

            .smallCircle {
                animation: smallCircleIn 1s 0s;
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.86, 0, .07, 1);
            }
        }

        &.opened {
            .bigCircle {
                animation: bigCircleOut 1s 0s;
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.86, 0, .07, 1);
            }

            .smallCircle {
                animation: smallCircleOut 1s 0s;
                animation-iteration-count: 1;
                animation-fill-mode: forwards;
                animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.86, 0, .07, 1);
            }
        }

        .bigCircle,
        .smallCircle {
            position: absolute;
            color: white;
        }

        .bigCircle {
            width: 2947px;
            height: 2947px;
            border-radius: 2947px;
            text-align: center;
            background: linear-gradient(204deg, #FFF 15.48%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 62.97%);
            opacity: 0.12;
        }

        .smallCircle {
            width: 1173px;
            height: 1173px;
            border-radius: 1173px;
            opacity: 0.06;
            background: linear-gradient(204deg, #FFF 15.48%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 50.01%);
        }
    }

@keyframes bigCircleOut {
  0% {
        left: -28%;
        top: -70px;
    }

    100% {
        left: 100%;
        top: -70px;
    }
}

@keyframes bigCircleIn {
  0% {
        left: 100%;
        top: -70px;
    }

    100% {
        left: -28%;
        top: -70px;
    }
}

@keyframes smallCircleOut {
  0% {
        left: -50%;
        top: 50%;
    }

    100% {
        left: -82%;
        top: 50%;
    }
}

@keyframes smallCircleIn {
  0% {
        left: -82%;
        top: 50%;
    }

    100% {
        left: -50%;
        top: 50%;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$('.circles').toggleClass('opened closing');
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="circles opened">
    <div class="bigCircle"></div>
    <div class="smallCircle"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1>Header element</h1>
        <p>Some paragrah element</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: the `working fiddle` doesn't work - or at least I cannot see anything close to your description. The CSS needs to be switched to scss rather than css as it is in the fiddle settings

Comment: That's funny, I checked it in several browsers and even incognito and it was working, I just edited it to use scss as well to see if the helps your case, thanks though.

Comment: Your `.circles` element currently has zero height. Position it absolute or fixed, and make it cover the whole relevant area (full body height, or viewport height, depending on whether this is supposed to scroll together with longer content, or not) - and then apply `overflow: hidden`.